# In Kubernetes controller what's the preferred way to get an item from the informer cache?

Tags: controller, kubernetes, kube-controller-manager

I am looking at following 2 examples, in the first [example](https://github.com/aaronlevy/kube-controller-demo/blob/master/reboot-controller/main.go#L155) A lister is used to retrieve the item.

In the [second example](https://github.com/trstringer/k8s-controller-core-resource/blob/master/controller.go#L102) , an index is used.

I am wondering which is the preferred way and way to retrieve an element from the local cache.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The examples you showed above, they both use **indexer**, if you go deeper you will see it.

For [First example](https://github.com/aaronlevy/kube-controller-demo/blob/master/reboot-controller/main.go#L155) (see [here](https://github.com/aaronlevy/kube-controller-demo/blob/7a6784a5953931c5b95896ad218760db893d2d29/vendor/k8s.io/client-go/listers/core/v1/node.go#L56))

```
// Get retrieves the Node from the index for a given name.
func (s *nodeLister) Get(name string) (*v1.Node, error) {
    obj, exists, err := s.indexer.GetByKey(name)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    if !exists {
        return nil, errors.NewNotFound(v1.Resource("node"), name)
    }
    return obj.(*v1.Node), nil
}
```

For [second example](https://github.com/trstringer/k8s-controller-core-resource/blob/master/controller.go#L102)

```
item, exists, err := c.informer.GetIndexer().GetByKey(keyRaw)
```

Comment: Right, thanks for pointing out. So for writing a custom controller either of the ways can be used right?

Comment: Right. I used this `c.Informer.GetIndexer().GetByKey(key)`. all the time